# Pattern based Transaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

We are using **Spring+JPA** for our **RESTful** web services application. This is a high transactional application and performs plenty of **CRUD** operations.

I am using `@Transaction` annotation on methods to perform the transaction and all is working fine.

I was just wondering if the **Transaction** can be managed outside the class in the **configuration file** based on **pattern** matching, i.e. all methods starting with **add/update/delete** can automatically be Transaction enabled (without the use of **@Transaction** annotation)?

Could someone please confirm if that’s **possible**?

If **‘Yes’** please provide me with some web link or example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course! In fact this was the only possible solution before Java 5 and `@Transactional` annotation. Look at [10.5.2 Example of declarative transaction implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) in Spring documentation. There you will find examples of transaction demarcation configuration via XML and AspectJ pointcuts.

This is a simple configuration excerpt from the documentation pointed above:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <!-- ... -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

As you can see, all methods with name prefixed with `get` are marked as *read-only*, while all other methods of `FooService` (`x.y.service.FooService.*(..))` pointcut) are transactional and not read-only.

As you can see using more verbose XML syntax gives you some great benefits like declarative and more flexible transaction demarcation, mainly thanks to AspectJ syntax (make sure to [learn it](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) first).

Comment: This is strictly not the answer I was looking for however I didn't get much responses and still exploring my options. But acepting it for the time being.